# Multiple Inheritance is complex for Language Consumers or Developers of the Languages?

Tags: oop, inheritance

So far within the articles I've read, it is mentioned that implementing Multiple Inheritance increases complexity. But I wonder if it increases the complexity for consumer developers' side or language developers' side?

Lets say, we could do something like this to get over the ambiguity:

```
class Artist{
   public void Draw(){ }
}

class Cowboy {
   public void Draw() { }
}

class Person : Artist, Cowboy{

}
```

Here it seems we have two same signatured methods, however a syntax such as `this.base.Artist.Draw()` or `this.base.Cowboy.Draw()` and also outside of type, from instance of it `person.base.Cowboy.Draw()` would looks sufficient enough to solve this ambiguity.

So what's the ambiguity and complexity we're talking about here. There are so many offerings out there but from a consumer perspective, it won't be that much complex we'd be dealing with.

`base` keyword can prevent the ambiguity in many cases :

1. `person.base.Cowbow.Draw();`
2. `(new Person()).base.Cowboy.Draw();`
3. `((Person) someInstance).base.Cowboy.Draw();`
4. `this.base.Cowboy.Draw();`
5. etc.

Comment: nice question. I think it should be on programmers though

Comment: how do you solve the ambiguity outside the class?

Comment: What would (new Person()).Draw() do?

Comment: @mrtofigh: Please read my question's last sentence before last paragraph.

Comment: @SimonSvensson: `(new Person()).base.Cowboy.Draw()` perhaps.

Comment: Diamond problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem

Comment: @SimonSvensson presumably, `(new Person()).Draw()` would fail to complile because of the ambiguity.  A scheme like this would therefore exacerbate the brittle base class problem.

Comment: I think this question has been asked and answered plenty of times. I wish .Net had multiple inheritance, but it's not going to happen.

Comment: There are those that would argue that Multiple Inheritance was intentionally left out of Java to avoid complexity.

Comment: This question assumes the presence of an oracle that can decide which version of Draw() needs to be called.  That oracle gets to be much more difficult to find when you further derive from Person.  It gets hopelessly ambiguous for a CowboyPainter class derived from Person, an object of which gets passed to a method that accepts Person.  That method has no hope of invoking the correct Draw().

Comment: I was quite surprised to see that this question was closed. I disagree with the reasoning as it is indeed related to SW development with the appropriate tags. Its even been upvoted twice, and not by me.

Answer (score 0):

If every access to the base class members has to prepend the appropriate base class name, then what's the point of inheriting from the base class? It could be argued that it would basically be the same as just making the base classes attributes of the Person class.

Another thing to consider is the complexity of the virtual table when using multiple inheritance. Using c++ as an example, multiple inheritance increases the size and complexity of the virtual table, thus decreasing the lookup performance.

Recently I took over a project that had 2 different classes with multiple inheritance (one inherited from 8 classes and the other from 6). Simply by refactoring the classes to use 'HAS-A' relations instead of 'IS-A' relations, I achieved a 5% performance increase. Granted this was an extreme case, but it serves to demonstrate the impacts that multiple inheritance can have.